# How to use small caps in stage directions of a play?

Tags: playwriting

I hate asking this, but for some reason I am utterly confused: is small caps not capitalized? I assumed if I wrote a characters name, "JASON", for instance, and then highlighted it and selected the small caps feature, that it would change it slightly--but it doesn't. I've never used it, a play submission calls for it, so this is my first time fiddling with small caps. So do I just write "jason" in lowercase letters and then change it to small caps? That seems to look right, but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question might vary depending on your word processor, operating platform, etc., but, near as I can tell from messing around on my Mac just now:

- Capital letters converted to small caps indeed stay their original size, so, if you want the entire name to appear with equally-sized letters, you would first type the name in lower-case letters before converting to small caps.
- One workaround to this is using ALL CAPS instead of small caps, and making the font size smaller. This way, it would't matter if you type `Jason`, `JASON`, or `jason`; all three would look the same.

As an example, I defined two styles in this document, one using ALL CAPS, and one using small caps. Then, I typed the names *JASON*, *Jason*, and *jason* into the document.

[image]

As you can see, the three in ALL CAPS look identical, no matter how I type the name. Therefore, I'd recommend using ALL CAPS with a slightly smaller font, to give the effect of small caps – no matter how the name is typed.

I would also highly recommend not changing the font entry by entry, but instead using a font style each time. That way, if you don't like the way it looks, you can simply tinker with the style, and the change will propagate automatically through your script.

Answer (score 0):

This is a stage play format question, and you don't list which submission format is specifically requested. Yale Drama Series play format calls for SMALL CAPS (which I'm not going to muck about trying to replicate here on SE).

SMALL CAPS is dependant on your typeface. Most popular typefaces define the SMALL CAPS size, kerning, leading, line spaces and other typographical features.

Your word processor should allow you to set a word as SMALL CAPITALS in the character font effects setting. Final Draft has it in Format > Style.

The submission guidelines should have stated something like 12-point Times New Roman. In that case just style it as SMALL CAPS and let the software do the spacing math.

Do not override the font size or any other font styling for the small caps. So don't add **bold** or *italics*.

Jason, JASON, jason and jaSON all look the same in SMALL CAPS but you should always type the name the same way because to computers they are different names. I use Jason so that if I ever lose formatting I can read his name without pause. Alternatively you can use JASON because you'll know that's a speaking character.

Comment: Though I mentioned that its provenance is for a play, the question is still strictly small caps: uppercase or lowercase. JASON in small caps, no matter what font, changes absolutely nothing. It has to be all lowercase.

Comment: SMALL CAPS means small CAPITALS. The underlying UTF/ANSI/ASCII code is (kind of) irrelevant. Open Type allows 65K characters so the typeface designer may (or may not) have included a small caps definition in their typeface. If typeface has small caps designed (in *Bold* and **Italic** too) then it is neither lowercase or uppercase but SMALLCAPS. i.e. a uniquely coded and designed typeface. If it does not have SMALLCAPS then the transformation happens in software. see http://ilovetypography.com/2008/02/20/small-caps/ I prefer Jason then JASON then jason if I was manually formatting SMALL CAPS